# Column names corresponding to maximum value

Tags: python, pandas

i have dataframe `df`

```
         0.0         1.0         2.0         3.0         4.0         5.0
0   0.537592    0.255088    0.102097    0.062989    0.024679    0.006685
1   0.063914    0.077319    0.173972    0.276244    0.121987    0.021594
```

i need take maximum in every row. so maximum in first line is `0.537592` [column name `0.0`], in second line it's `0.276244` [colum name `3.0`]

so i need df like

```
        label        
0        0.0
1        3.0
```

how i can make this?
tried something like `subs.loc[subs['0.0'] == subs['0.0'].max(axis=1)]` but it doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for this:

```
df.idxmax(axis=1).to_frame(name='Label')

   Label
0   0.0
1   3.0
```